# How can I get a pdf from https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/onetype.tex?

Tags: tex-core

How can I get this pdf https://tug.org/texshowcase/onetype.pdf starting from this source https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/onetype.tex ?

`tex onetype.tex` gives me

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(./onetype.tex
kpathsea: Running mktextfm padr9alt
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input padr9alt
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf padr9alt
! I can't find file `padr9alt'.
```

Comment: Have you installed the necessary fonts?

Comment: @TeXnician I do not know. A google search for `padr9alt` did not give me any clue...

Comment: Well this notation corresponds to a "real" font name. I currently do not know which one, but you could try substituting them by fonts you have (maybe Computer Modern or the like).

Comment: that's trying to use agaramond. You can find some support files in the psfonts package (in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt).  But without the real fonts you can't use them. Why are you trying to compile this old document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have found it as a showcase and I liked it. I need a showcase with source and a way to build the source.